# Mysql Update with selection min/max count group

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-update, max, min

i have a simple table like this:

```
id  grouped  type_error
--  -------  ------------------ 
1   1-0      TL           
2   1-0      TL           
3   1-0      TL           
4   1-1      TL           
5   1-2      TL      
6   1-2      TL      
7   1-3      TL      
8   1-3      TL      
9   1-3      TL      
10  1-3      TL
```

i just want to update the table to be like this:

```
id  grouped  type_error
--  -------  ------------------ 
1   1-0      FN           
2   1-0      FN           
3   1-0      FN           
4   1-1      TL           
5   1-2      TL      
6   1-2      TL      
7   1-3      FN      
8   1-3      FN      
9   1-3      FN      
10  1-3      FN
```

i want to update where grouped count is min 3 and max 5:

i just have i query like this:

```
update errorlog set type_error = 'FN' where id in
(select group_concat(id) as ids from errorlog where ids > 2 group by grouped)
```

but, its not working. I get the error

> Unknown column 'ids' in 'where clause'

Comment: Don't understand your example result. `grouped count is min 3 and max 5` but in the rows with ids 1 to 3 the gruoped field is 1-0

Comment: If you're interested in the count, why include a group_concat

Comment: Could you post the mysql error please?

Comment: @JochenSchultz Unknown column 'ids' in 'where clause'.

Comment: @Alfabravo, sori if my english is bad. i need to update where count(id) is betwen 3 and 4 with group by grouped coulumn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution, with a sub-select:

```
UPDATE errorlog SET type_error = 'FN'
WHERE grouped IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT grouped 
    FROM errorlog 
    GROUP BY grouped 
    HAVING COUNT(id) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
  )x
);
```

> **Here you can find a working demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/311a01/1/0

Comment: i'ts work with a more subquery select. `UPDATE errorlog SET type_error = 'FN' 
WHERE grouped IN ( SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT grouped AS g 
    FROM errorlog er
    GROUP BY er.grouped 
    HAVING COUNT(er.id) BETWEEN 3 AND 5) AS e
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET type_error = 'FN' 
WHERE grouped IN (
    SELECT grouped 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY grouped 
    HAVING COUNT(id) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
)
```

Unfortunatly yields an error in mysql:

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'errorlog' for update in FROM clause
```

So expanding on [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3840840/sebastian-brosch) answer i would do this in two steps:

```
MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> drop table IF EXISTS targets;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> create temporary table IF NOT EXISTS targets as
    -> (SELECT grouped
    ->     FROM errorlog
    ->     GROUP BY grouped
    ->     HAVING COUNT(id) BETWEEN 3 AND 5);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> UPDATE errorlog a SET type_error = 'FN'
    -> WHERE exists (select 1 from targets t where t.grouped = a.grouped);
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 7  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]>
MariaDB [test]> select * from errorlog order by id;
+------+---------+------------+
| id   | grouped | type_error |
+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | 1-0     | FN         |
|    2 | 1-0     | FN         |
|    3 | 1-0     | FN         |
|    4 | 1-1     | TL         |
|    5 | 1-2     | TL         |
|    6 | 1-2     | TL         |
|    7 | 1-3     | FN         |
|    8 | 1-3     | FN         |
|    9 | 1-3     | FN         |
|   10 | 1-3     | FN         |
+------+---------+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: with @Sebastian explain, i use more select to ignore the error. it's look like this: `UPDATE errorlog SET type_error = 'FN' 
WHERE grouped IN ( SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT grouped AS g 
    FROM errorlog er
    GROUP BY er.grouped 
    HAVING COUNT(er.id) BETWEEN 3 AND 5) AS e
)`

Comment: Nice. Works perfectly.